# Styled breadcrumb navigation using MVCSiteMapPath

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using the MVCSiteMapProvider here: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider  and trying to style my breadcrumb navigation so it has a look similar to http://www.psd100.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/breadcrumb-navigation-psd-free-download022701.jpg)

Has anyone had success with this? Maybe by generating a ul & li based on the current page your'e on. Right now I'm getting the breadcrumbs but I want to add an arrow background image to them, and unless I can get a ul & li, it's not possible to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cant see the gif image

Comment: okay, fixed. sorry about that.

Comment: I think you can do it with js, adding a style to each element.
I saw something similar with the jqsimplemenu (google it).

Comment: I ended up just creating an html helper class and use it to create a list and applied css to this list.

Comment: Yes, I think I did the same in other project. It it works great.
Post your own answer and 2 days after mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no need to create your own HTML helper (although that is certainly an option). All of the HTML helpers in MvcSiteMapProvider are templated. You can customize the default templates by editing them in the /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ folder.

For the sitemap path HTML helper, you would want to edit the SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml (or SiteMapPathHelper.aspx) file.

Note that you can also utilize template naming to use more than one template on the same HTML helper.

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath("MyTemplateName")
```

This would match a template named MyTemplateName.cshtml or MyTemplateName.aspx.